# Jetpack Compose LazyColumn recomposition with remember()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Ive been trying out Jetpack Compose and ran into something with the `LazyColumn` list and `remember()`.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApp{
                MyScreen()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyApp(content: @Composable () -> Unit){
    ComposeTestTheme {
        // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
        Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
            content()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyScreen( names: List<String> = List(1000) {"Poofy #$it"}) {
    NameList( names, Modifier.fillMaxHeight())
}

@Composable
fun NameList( names: List<String>, modifier: Modifier = Modifier ){
    LazyColumn( modifier = modifier ){
        items( items = names ) { name ->
            val counter = remember{ mutableStateOf(0) }

            Row(){
                Text(text = "Hello $name")
                Counter(
                    count = counter.value,
                    updateCount = { newCount -> counter.value = newCount } )
            }
            Divider(color = Color.Black)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Counter(count: Int, updateCount: (Int) -> Unit) {
    Button( onClick = {updateCount(count+1)} ){
        Text("Clicked $count times")
    }
}
```

This runs and creates a list of 1000 rows where each row says "Hello Poofy #N" followed by a button that says "Clicked N times".

It all works fine but if I click a button to update its count that count will not persist when it is scrolled offscreen and back on.

The `LazyColumn` "recycling" recomposes the row and the count. In the above sample the counter is hoisted up into `NameList()` but I have tried it unhoisted in `Counter()`. Neither works.

What is the proper way to remember the count? Must I store it in an array in the activity or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The representations for `items` are recycled, and with the new `index` the value of `remember` is reset. This is expected behavior, and you should not expect this value to persist.

You don't need to keep it in the activity, you just need to move it out of the `LazyColumn`. For example, you can store it in a mutable state list, as shown here:

```
val counters = remember { names.map { 0 }.toMutableStateList() }
LazyColumn( modifier = modifier ){
    itemsIndexed(items = names) { i, name ->
        Row(){
            Text(text = "Hello $name")
            Counter(
                count = counters[i],
                updateCount = { newCount -> counters[i] = newCount } )
        }
        Divider(color = Color.Black)
    }
}
```

Or in a mutable state map:

```
val counters = remember { mutableStateMapOf<Int, Int>() }
LazyColumn( modifier = modifier ){
    itemsIndexed(items = names) { i, name ->
        Row(){
            Text(text = "Hello $name")
            Counter(
                count = counters[i] ?: 0,
                updateCount = { newCount -> counters[i] = newCount } )
        }
        Divider(color = Color.Black)
    }
}
```

Note that [`remember`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary?hl=vi#remember(kotlin.Function0)) will also be reset when screen rotates, consider using [`rememberSaveable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/saveable/package-summary#rememberSaveable(kotlin.Array,androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.Saver,kotlin.String,kotlin.Function0)) instead of storing the data inside a view model.

Read more about state in Compose in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state)